# Configuring GET Request htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

My .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
```

I need to remake it to "simple" GET request.

From http://mydomain.co/page?cat=smth

To http://mydomain.co/page/smth

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php?cat=$2 [NC,L]
```

Can anybody show me my mistakes?

Comment: _“Can anybody show me my mistakes?”_ - well [ask] can at least explain to you how we expect you to _properly describe the problem_. I assume it is “not working” then? How exactly, what happens? And are you sure you got the “from” and “to” right? Normally people want to rewrite from the “pretty” URL to the one that uses a query string internally, not the other way around.

Comment: "How exactly, what happens?" It works like /index.php to /index, but when i'm trying to make get request like index/smth it's crushes with Internal Server Error

Comment: Then what mistakes are you asking about?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you've tried to edit above is there to remove your `.php` extension. Simply adding `?cat=$2` onto the end of it will not give you clean URLs and will cause the internal error that you're getting....

What you can do is use the following rule in your `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^page/([^/]*)$ /page?cat=$1 [L]
```

It will leave you with the URL: `http://mydomain.co/page/smth`

Make sure you clear your cache before testing this.

Comment: Understood my previous mistake, but it still crushes with Internal Servet Error :(